# how to split a string and extract columns in Unix

Tags: unix, extract

Suppose I have strings :

```
au sujet de l article card -> your advice about rule (0.000000082860230)
au sujet de l article card -> would therefore like some (0.000000082860230)
```

in general like that :

```
 6 words -> n words (value)
```

I m searching for an idea to extract the 6 words with the value like this for example

```
 au sujet de l article card 0.000000082860230
 au sujet de l article card 0.000000082860230
```

Any idea please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for `awk`:

```
echo "$line" | awk '{ value=$NF; gsub(/[\(\)]/,"",value); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,value }'
```

This prints the first 6 fields, and the last field after removing parentheses via regexp.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, with Perl you could use:

```
$ echo "$line" | perl -lne 'print "$1 $2" if /(.*) -> .* \((.*)\)/'
```

Comment: mean `-lne` for more lines? :)

Comment: @jm666 - nice, I didn't know about the `-l` switch. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like

```
echo "$line" | sed -e 's/->.*(//' -e 's/)$//'
```

This should work... Despite it's not very failsafe (e.g. it does not complain, when you have `20 words -> 1 char (value)` instead of `6 words -> n words (value)`)

Comment: Ok thank you, and suppose i have a file which contain a lot number of sentence?

Comment: When you have one set per line, you could do

    while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | sed -e 's/->.*(//' -e 's/)$//' # >> out.txt
    done < file.txt